# Google contacts api endpoint authenticated user contacts name is blank

Tags: node.js, google-contacts-api, google-authentication

Im using https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&oauth_token='+accessToken+'&max-results=10000&v=3.0
to get authenticated user contacts
and it's  returning contact list of authenticated user but the contacts name is blank, if one contact updated in gmail then that contact getting name,  why is that happening? 
Is there any wrong in above url

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the contact name from the `title`

For example, you can get the value from the title field from following title field:

```
"title": {
    "$t": "Tester Name", 
     "type": "text"
 },
```

Its normal that some contacts might have a blank title and you can use a placeholder for their names.

Comment: I'm getting some contacts like this                                       "title": {
    "$t": "", 
     "type": "text"
 }